selecting the correct paint and primer
A couple of years ago I repainted many of my wood trims and doors (they were painted with a glossy oil based paint that had turned yellow) using Sherwin-Williams Multipurpose waterbased acrylic-alkyd primer and then SW Pro Classic waterbased acrylic-alkyd. The end result was beautiful and 10-12 years later the color has not changed a bit and still as smooth as day 1.
Now I wanted to paint the closet doors/trims and shelves with the same paints, but SW has discontinued the multipurpose waterbased acrylic-alkyd primer. What should I use now as a primer knowing that i still will use the Pro Classic acrylic-alkyd as a final coat? These doors/trims are currently painted with an oil based glossy paint that has yellowed over time.

You need to go to a SW store or supplier to purchase what you need. Why not ask their recommendation.
